# Specify a different module for worker using Webpack's ProvidePlugin?

Tags: webpack

I would like to use Webpack's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to replace a free variable with a function. In workers, I want to replace it with a different implementation.

Neither webpack's [worker-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/worker-loader/) nor GoogleChromeLabs' [WorkerPlugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin) seem to allow this. The latter was promising but—despite its claim that it "doesn't run any of your configured Webpack plugins when bundling worker code", the ProvidePlugin in the main config interacts with the one passed to the WorkerLoader.

Here's is a simple example config (the plugins part only):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    _X_: ['/path/to/a', 'default'],
  }),
  new WorkerPlugin({
    globalObject: false,
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _X_: ['/path/to/b', 'default'],
      }),
    ],
  }),
]
```

My question is: **How can I specify a different implementation (module) for the free variable in workers?**

I'm not tied to any particular plugin or loader (ProvidePlugin, worker-loader, worker-plugin), but the more standard the better.

Comment: Is only variable is acceptable for your case? (I mean if you can use a module I can help there with DefinePlugin or NormalModuleReplacementPlugin)

Comment: if module (not variable) replacement is ok for you, take a look at https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-worker-module-replacement .
in worst case you can write your own plugin to work in worker, which will be a 99% copy-paste from ProvidePlugin, but just with some conditions

Comment: Thanks @nickbullock. Will this only work for direct dependents of the worker module or all transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I don't know how to specify different implementation of variable, but I know to do it for a module.
I just updated the [repo](https://github.com/nickbullock/webpack-worker-module-replacement/blob/master/webpack.config.js), hope it will help you.
Now it works even with deep worker dependencies.

Comment: This does seem to work! I was able to use the `ProvidePlugin` to point to a module, then use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to replace its request. Unfortunately, in my project the build just hangs…

Still, since this seems to work for the reduced case, do you think you could update your answer with details from the repo? (Since SO answers aren't supposed to be links to external resources.)

Thanks!!

Comment: For some reason, `resource.contextInfo.compiler` is always undefined in my app 